# Querying a Devise users table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, devise

I just set up the Devise auth library and I am confused about how it is meant to be queried.

For example, before when I made my own users table, I made this user.rb file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key:uid
end
```

And I was able to query by uid like this:

```
@User = User.find(1)
print @User
```

Now that Devise added a number of columns and the users.rb file looks like this:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
         :first_name, :last_name, :organization_name

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

The above code to query this table does not work and I am not sure how it is meant to be queried.

Also, I am not sure if I should do something like this

```
rails generate devise User
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I see that your class is now named "Users", it should be named "User" like in your previous snippet. Are you sure you still have a User with a UID of 1? You could try doing User.first.uid and see what that returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a good practice to override the Rails default primary keys, perhaps you could try finding your users the following way instead:

```
@User = User.find_by_uid(1)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware I was overriding Rails default primary keys.  I think I wouldn't want to do that.  I tried to use your idea and I got this error: undefined method `find_by_uid' for #<Class:0x9716778>

Comment: Rails provides its own primary key by default to all models. Perhaps this is why after installing Devise your user model doesn't work correctly.

I think I misunderstood you, do you actually have an attribute called uid? If you were trying to use the actual record id, you should use the method as User.find_by_id(1).

There's more about Dynamic att finders here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html